# Since I've put my VS project on OneDrive I got error: Couldn't process file MainForm.resx... and I can't compile anymore

Tags: visual-studio, onedrive

Since I've put my **VisualStudio C# project** on **OneDrive** (maybe it was not a good idea...) I got the error:

```
Couldn't process file MainForm.resx due to its being in the Internet or 
Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark 
of the web if you want to process these files.
```

If I move my project outside it works again of course.

Before it was on a google drive folder and it was also working correctly ... Don't understand how Microsoft can miss this kind of thing...

I've already check all the messages related to this issue and none of it worked:

- I have no unlock option on the file
- the powershell command didn't work
- i've updated MainForm.resx clean and rebuild

Thx in advance!!!

Comment: Use a proper source control system like Git and don't expect OneDrive and Visual Studio can work well with each other.

Comment: @LexLi: I already use GIT for Source Control, the purpose is not the same in my opinion. Why do you think it could not work well togheter?

Comment: Google that, and you can find tons of issues when saving source code on OneDrive. Neither OneDrive nor Visual Studio is open sourced, so we can only assume that Microsoft never designs them to work together.

Comment: @LexLi Ok I'll follow your advice ;-)!